Python + Svelte, how to use the local filesystem
I want to use Svelte framework for the frontend of my app.
But if I do it, I must use a upload file by a <input type="file">, it's very slow.
I want to interact with the local filesystem without the slowness of an upload.
I make a small exemple with Flask :
import os

from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure upload folder
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "upload_folder"

app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

# Ensure the upload folder exists
os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER, exist_ok=True)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "file" not in request.files:
            return "No file part"
        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return "No selected file"
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
            return "File uploaded successfully"
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    """


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


Are you planning on using this solution only yourself locally on your own computer? Or host it on a server so anyone can use it? If locally, then just entering paths to the files in the GUI, and then send these paths to the Python program will work. If hosting on a server, then the GUI needs to read the file, and send its content to the Python program. That can be achieved using the <form> element with <input type="file">.

Just locally, but I want a interactive thing (like drag n'drop or )

OK, that will be possible using Svelte for the GUI (frontend) and Python for the backend. But your backend needs to expose a web API the frontend can use to send it the files the user has selected, and to retrieve the file your Python program will produce. Without any specific questions, I don't think we can give you any more advice than that.

To summarize, I want to do the same as a Electron app (like VScode which can interact with the local filesystem) but with a Python backend (and without use Electron).

OK. An Electron app includes a Node.js runtime environment, so I recommend you to build your app using SvelteKit then. In SvelteKit, you use Svelte as the frontend, and SvelteKit as the backend. SvelteKit is built on Node.js, so you can call functions in Node.js to run your Python files.

Note: I don't know Electron well, but I imagine you can skip SvelteKit, and call Node.js functions directly in your Electron code. But with SvelteKit you get routing for free, so I would still recommend you to use it if you need routing.

I actually found a solution:
https://github.com/python-eel/Eel
A lib to expose python function on html page, so I expose a function, call it with a html button, call the native tkinter.filedialog to open a filedialog and I get my file list.
